# Pi-Hole + Unbound ==> Unbound anchor not ok // SERVFAIL

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, server, dns, pi-hole

**Problem with unbound and pi-hole**

I followed the official guide for installing **Unbound** alongside **Pi-hole** for my network, see [Setting up Pi-hole as a recursive DNS server solution](https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/unbound/)

A week ago I first followed this guide with a fresh installed Raspbian (lite) and everything worked out of the box.
But today I followed the guide again (with a fresh install also) for my Pi-Zero at home and I just can't get unbound to work...

With `dig pi-hole.net @127.0.0.1 -p 5353` I always get "*SERVFAIL*" and if I look at the unbound.service I either get:

`unbound[1187]: [1187:0] info: failed to prime trust anchor -- could not fetch DNSKEY rrset . DNSKEY IN`

or something along the line of `the anchor is NOT ok and could not be fixed`

I have no idea why that keeps happening. I tried `sudo unbound-anchor -v -a /var/lib/unbound/root.key` (and other possible remedies I found online - like uninstall / using unbound-user etc) to reset the root.key-file but the anchor still fails.

Any help would be appreciated!